# Build GDB android

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk, gdb, cross-platform

I am trying to build the GDB and I have checked out the sources from here :

https://secure-web.cisco.com/1gNMaTaLSpyPf04-64vyJyKpMnhYszFwToxEd5acy6VS3P271v2Vw2kWu-o5O16GAU92fTpsG5ezF48gddoDV7Adx8PaRyVUyENTYoGhf4DAL5SCpsboaD9mL8rtLqTcK7yirl321lqD9Cfnoz5vju88CQIffq80iTEn4g5SSY7g/https%3A%2F%2Fandroid.googlesource.com%2Ftoolchain%2Fgdb.git

I am using the same toolchain I use to compile my NDK application adding the bin folder to my path and runned the config script:

./configure --host=arm-linux-androideabi

I get this build error :

.././libiberty/getpagesize.c:64:1: error: redefinition of 'getpagesize'
/home/xxxxx/android-ndk/arm_a14_tools/bin/../sysroot/usr/include/unistd.h:174:23: note: previous definition of 'getpagesize' was here
Makefile:679: recipe for target 'getpagesize.o' failed
make[2]: *** [getpagesize.o] Error 1
Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I met this too. I found two solution.

```
1 diff --git a/libiberty/configure b/libiberty/configure
index d8890a1..720dc5e 100755
--- a/libiberty/configure
+++ b/libiberty/configure
@@ -6248,6 +6248,12 @@  if test -z "${setobjs}"; then

   case "${host}" in

+  *-*-android*)
+    # On android, getpagesize is defined in unistd.h as a static inline
+    # function, which AC_CHECK_FUNCS does not handle properly.
+    ac_cv_func_getpagesize=yes
+    ;;
+
   *-*-mingw32*)
     # Under mingw32, sys_nerr and sys_errlist exist, but they are
     # macros, so the test below won't find them.
diff --git a/libiberty/configure.ac b/libiberty/configure.ac
index 868be8e..e21e3aa 100644
--- a/libiberty/configure.ac
+++ b/libiberty/configure.ac
@@ -600,6 +600,12 @@  if test -z "${setobjs}"; then

   case "${host}" in

+  *-*-android*)
+    # On android, getpagesize is defined in unistd.h as a static inline
+    # function, which AC_CHECK_FUNCS does not handle properly.
+    ac_cv_func_getpagesize=yes
+    ;;
+
   *-*-mingw32*)
     # Under mingw32, sys_nerr and sys_errlist exist, but they are
     # macros, so the test below won't find them.
```

Reference: https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/541034/

2 As a quick-fix hack temporarily commenting out the section 
in unistd.h:

```
#if 0
static __inline__ int getpagesize(void) {
  extern unsigned int __page_size;
  return __page_size;
}
#endif
```

Refercence: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gdb.devel/33166